# Render-Time Configuration in React-Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I was recently watching the react conference of 2017, and during the speech of Leland Richardson, i came across this title:

> Render Time Configuration in React Native

The following code was given as an example in the above title:

`<Navigator.config
title="Screen Title"
onAppear={ () => console.log("something") }`

In which he talks about some configuration that is possbile during the rendering time. My question is:

> What is the different between the Render-Time configuration and other configuration methods in native solutions?

Thanks in advance.